# sql query that holds value by their rank per each id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create columns that hold the time value ranked by id.
for instance the original table is only:

| id   | rnk    | time |

and the desired query answer table is:

| id | rnk | time | second | third | fourth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 13:21:17.093 | 13:21:17.184 | 13:33:00.790 | 13:47:27.566 |
| 123 | 2 | 13:21:17.184 | 13:21:17.184 | 13:33:00.790 | 13:47:27.566 |
| 123 | 3 | 13:33:00.790 | 13:21:17.184 | 13:33:00.790 | 13:47:27.566 |
| 123 | 4 | 13:47:27.566 | 13:21:17.184 | 13:33:00.790 | 13:47:27.566 |
| 123 | 5 | 13:57:31.382 | 13:21:17.184 | 13:33:00.790 | 13:47:27.566 |
| 789 | 1 | 08:45:29.365 | 08:48:09.788 | 08:58:20.216 | null |
| 789 | 2 | 08:48:09.788 | 08:48:09.788 | 08:58:20.216 | null |
| 789 | 3 | 08:58:20.216 | 08:48:09.788 | 08:58:20.216 | null |

what it tried to do is to use as many joins as the number of columns i need to add and that just not scalable solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can sort this using `tablefunc` [crosstab function](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/create-pivot-table-postgresql/)

I built a similar example (with integer seconds instead of time)

```
CREATE TABLE example (
id int,
rnk int,
seconds int
);

insert into example values (123,1,'100');
insert into example values (123,1,'120');
insert into example values (123,1,'130');
insert into example values (123,1,'140');
insert into example values (123,1,'150');
insert into example values (123,2,'110');
insert into example values (123,2,'112');
insert into example values (123,2,'115');
insert into example values (123,2,'118');
insert into example values (123,2,'119');
insert into example values (123,3,'100');
insert into example values (123,3,'120');
insert into example values (123,3,'130');
insert into example values (123,3,'140');
insert into example values (123,3,'150');
insert into example values (123,4,'110');
insert into example values (123,4,'112');
insert into example values (123,4,'115');
insert into example values (789,1,'11');
insert into example values (789,1,'20');
insert into example values (789,1,'30');
insert into example values (789,1,'50');
insert into example values (789,1,'70');
insert into example values (789,2,'90');
insert into example values (789,2,'111');
```

Using the `crosstab` as follows (with the trick of combining `id` and `rank` columns into one)

```
SELECT * FROM 
crosstab(
    'select cast(id as text) || ''~'' || cast(rnk as text) id_rank, 
        RANK() over (PARTITION BY id, rnk order by seconds)::int ranking, 
        seconds 
    from example 
    order by 1,2') AS ct 
(id text, first int, second int, third int, fourth int);
```

result

```
  id   | first | second | third | fourth
-------+-------+--------+-------+--------
 123~1 |   100 |    120 |   130 |    140
 123~2 |   110 |    112 |   115 |    118
 123~3 |   100 |    120 |   130 |    140
 123~4 |   110 |    112 |   115 |
 789~1 |    11 |     20 |    30 |     50
 789~2 |    90 |    111 |       |
(6 rows)
```

Do I need the `fifth` result? I just need to add the `fifth` column (check the `additional_fifth`) in my `crosstab` definition

```
SELECT * FROM 
crosstab(
    'select cast(id as text) || ''~'' || cast(rnk as text) id_rank, 
        RANK() over (PARTITION BY id, rnk order by seconds)::int ranking, 
        seconds 
    from example 
    order by 1,2') AS ct 
(id text, first int, second int, third int, fourth int, additional_fifth int);
```

And there we are

```
  id   | first | second | third | fourth | additional_fifth
-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+------------------
 123~1 |   100 |    120 |   130 |    140 |              150
 123~2 |   110 |    112 |   115 |    118 |              119
 123~3 |   100 |    120 |   130 |    140 |              150
 123~4 |   110 |    112 |   115 |        |
 789~1 |    11 |     20 |    30 |     50 |               70
 789~2 |    90 |    111 |       |        |
(6 rows)
```